# Angular 2 - Error: (SystemJS) Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)

Tags: angular

I have a slight issue:

Error: (SystemJS) Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)

I have a component where I import another module:
Here is videos.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { VideosComponent } from './videos.component';
import { EditorModule, SharedModule, ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GalleryModule } from '../../components/gallery/gallery.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, EditorModule, SharedModule, ButtonModule,  GalleryModule],
  declarations: [VideosComponent],
  exports: [VideosComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class VideosModule { }
```

As you can see I am importing the Gallery Module. If I remove this then the error goes away.
Lets continue down the rabbit hole.

Here is the gallery gallery.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { ViewerComponent } from '../viewer/viewer.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from './gallery.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [GalleryComponent, ViewerComponent],
  exports: [GalleryModule],
  providers: []
})
export class GalleryModule { }
```

Here is the gallery.component.ts

```
import {Component, NgZone, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { ViewerComponent } from '../viewer/viewer.component';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


interface IImage {
  url: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  date: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'sd-gallery',
  templateUrl: 'gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryComponent {

  @ViewChild('galleryContainer') galleryContainer: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('asyncLoadingContainer') asyncLoadingContainer: ElementRef;

  thumbnailBasePath = 'assets/img/gallery/preview_xxs/';
  currentIdx: number = 0;
  galleryBasePath: string = 'assets/img/gallery/';
  showBig: boolean = false;
  images: any[] = [{ url: '' }];
  gallery: any[] = [];
  imgIterations = 1;
  allImagesLoaded = false;


  // TypeScript public modifiers
  constructor( private _ngZone: NgZone, private http: Http ) {

  }


  private ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.fetchDataAndRender();
  }

  private fetchDataAndRender() {
    this.http.get(this.galleryBasePath + 'data.json')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.images = data;
        this.render();
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => undefined);
  }

  private render() {
    let tempRow = [this.images[0]];
    let rowIndex = 0;
    let i = 0;

    for (i; i < this.imgIterations && i < this.images.length; i++) {
      while (this.images[i + 1] && this.shouldAddCandidate(tempRow, this.images[i + 1])) {
        i++;
      }
      if (this.images[i + 1]) {
        tempRow.pop();
      }
      this.gallery[rowIndex++] = tempRow;

      tempRow = [this.images[i + 1]];
    }

    this.scaleGallery();

    if (i >= this.images.length) {
      this.allImagesLoaded = true;
    } else {
      this.checkForAsyncReload();
    }
  }

  private shouldAddCandidate(imgRow: IImage[], candidate: IImage): boolean {
    let oldDifference = this.calcIdealHeight() - this.calcRowHeight(imgRow);
    imgRow.push(candidate);
    let newDifference = this.calcIdealHeight() - this.calcRowHeight(imgRow);

    return Math.abs(oldDifference) > Math.abs(newDifference);
  }

  private calcRowHeight(imgRow: IImage[]) {
    let xsum = this.calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow);

    let ratio = this.getGalleryWidth() / xsum;
    let rowHeight = imgRow[0].height * ratio;

    return rowHeight;
  }

  private scaleGallery() {
    this.gallery.forEach((imgRow) => {
      let xsum = this.calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow);

      if (imgRow !== this.gallery[this.gallery.length - 1]) {
        let ratio = this.getGalleryWidth() / xsum;

        imgRow.forEach((img: any) => {
          img.width = img.width * ratio;
          img.height = img.height * ratio;
        })
      }
    })
  }

  private calcOriginalRowWidth(imgRow: IImage[]) {
    let xsum = 0;
    imgRow.forEach((img) => {
      let individualRatio = this.calcIdealHeight() / img.height;
      img.width = img.width * individualRatio;
      img.height = this.calcIdealHeight();
      xsum += img.width + 1;
    });

    return xsum;
  }

  private calcIdealHeight() {
      return (this.getGalleryWidth() / 8) + 70;
  }

  private openImageViewer(img: any) {
    this.showBig = undefined;
    this.showBig = true;
    this.currentIdx = this.images.indexOf(img);
  }

  private getGalleryWidth() {
    if (this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth === 0) {
      // IE11
      return this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
    }
    return this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth;
  }

  private checkForAsyncReload() {
    if (!this.allImagesLoaded) {
      var loadingDiv: any = this.asyncLoadingContainer.nativeElement;

      var elmTop = loadingDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var elmBottom = loadingDiv.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

      var isVisible = (elmTop >= 0) && (elmBottom <= window.innerHeight);

      if (isVisible) {
        this.imgIterations += 5;
        this.fetchDataAndRender();
      }
    }
  }

  private onClose() {
    this.showBig = false;
  }

  private onResize() {
    this.render();
  }


}
```

I will not include with the viewer part because even if I remove it from the gallery html/module I still get the same issue.

Thanks all!

- Here is an image of the full exception:
  https://postimg.org/image/fmf7qzksn/

Comment: Hey Pete, I realized you posted some of my code about my Angular 2 image gallery here on Stackoverflow (https://github.com/BenjaminBrandmeier/ng2imggallery). It seems like you found help already, thanks to Stefan. If you experience more problems feel free to create an issue on GitHub and I'm happy to assist.

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistakes in your `GalleryModule`, one of them is probably causing the error you are getting.

**First**

`BrowserModule` should only be imported in your root module. (most commonly, this is `AppModule`) You should import `CommonModule` instead because that's probably all you need in `GalleryModule`. (`CommonModule` contains common directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`)

**Second**

Remove `GalleryModule` from its exports:

```
exports: [GalleryModule]
```

Why would you export `GalleryModule` from `GalleryModule` itself? This line is already doing all the work:

```
export class GalleryModule { }
```

If I had to bet, I'd say this is what's causing the error.

Comment: @Pete That's because your `templateUrl`'s are incorrect, you need to provide full path, for example `templateUrl: 'app/gallery/gallery.component.html'`, name of the html file itself is not enough, component has to know where to look for it exactly.

Comment: All my other components work this way, buy having the components html in the same folder and referenced the same way with the template Url. Each component has its own folder to store all the files relating to it.

Comment: @Pete Well, that's a whole another problem, you should google and find out what it is. The problem you asked about is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, it was caused by including the prototype.js library on my web page.  After I removed prototype, my Angular 2 app loaded successfully.